# blitting an image onto a sprite pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have a class for my enemy and an image called "fov.png" which is just a cone. I want to `blit` the image of the cone onto the enemy to act as a field of view where you will get caught if you collide (which I will implement after) but I am only able to `blit` the image onto the screen.

When I run the code shown below the cone image just doesn't show up. If I change the coordinates from `(self.rect.x, self.rect.y)` to say `(0, 0)` it displays it on top of the screen and not the game behind therefore when I move around the map it stays in the corner.

```py
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, position, surface = pygame.Surface((tilesize, tilesize))):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = surface
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=position)
        self.hitbox = self.rect.inflate(-10, -10)
        self.movement = 3

    def move(self, group, player):
        global walk_count
        global frame_count
        global move_up
        global move_down
        enemy_rect = self.hitbox.copy()
        display.blit(load(path("Images", "fov.png")), (self.rect.x, self.rect.y)) ## my attempt ##
        if walk_count >= len(move_up) * 16:
            walk_count = 0
        else:
            walk_count = 0
        if self.movement == 3:
            self.image = move_down[(walk_count // 16) % len(move_down)]
            walk_count += 1
        elif self.movement == -3:
            self.image = move_up[(walk_count // 16) % len(move_up)]
            walk_count += 1
        self.hitbox.move_ip(0, self.movement)
        self.rect.center = self.hitbox.center
        for sprite in group:
            if sprite.hitbox.colliderect(self.hitbox):
                self.hitbox = enemy_rect
                self.movement = -self.movement
        if self.hitbox.colliderect(player.hitbox):
            return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not update self.rect.x and self.rect.y, therefore its blit location does not differ.

Try:

```
        self.rect.x, self.rect.y = self.hitbox.x,self.hitbox.y
```

instead of:

```
        self.rect.center = self.hitbox.center
```

Comment: the image still isnt being displayed when i tried that

Comment: Do you enter in this block of code ?


`for sprite in group:
     if sprite.hitbox.colliderect(self.hitbox):
          self.hitbox = enemy_rect
            self.movement = -self.movement`

If not the location of self.rectx and y will not change.

Comment: no i replaced `self.rect.center = self.hitbox.center` with it

Comment: I cannot help you much without being able to reproduce the error, sorry